# Are there negative consequences to disabling audit policies?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, event-log

I'm the sole user of my own laptop running Windows 8.1. After doing a bit of research into this (eg. [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/774728/event-id4797-an-attempt-was-made-to-query-the-existence-of-a-blank-password-fo) and [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn319056.aspx)), I can see how this might be useful for a company laptop.

But is there any benefit to running these audits on my own, personal, laptop where I am the Administrator? Are there any negative consequences of disabling the audit policy using `auditpol /clear`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in the information the logs have and aren't going to look at them, then having them isn't helping you a lot. Nothing technically bad is going to happen if you disable them.

Audits can list logons and logoffs, and so might help you determine whether somebody's been using your machine without permission. Enabling more audits could give you extra insight into what services on your system are doing, if you're interested in internals. If you do programming involving system-level stuff, audits could help with troubleshooting.

Other than those uses, I can't think of a compelling reason to not disable audits. Of course, you can turn them off and on as necessary; `auditpol /clear` isn't permanent.